# How do I hide vertices not visible to the camera?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm following a character modelling tutorial, and I noticed that the face of my character appears different to how it is in the video - I can see the vertices which are hidden to the camera, as if the material were translucent. Here is a screenshot of what I mean (in the right frame):

[image: Translucent face]

In the video, it appears in the following manner:

[image: Face as seen in video]

As you can see, none of the vertices which are hidden from the camera are visible. How can I achieve the same appearance in edit mode? I tried enabling backface culling although this did not work.

Comment: you must have disabled the button Limit Selection to Visible (on the bottom of the 3D view, button with a cube)

Comment: @moonboots thank you! that's indeed what i'd done

Answer (score 1):

As per moonboots's comment, I had disabled Limit Selection to Visible, so I just needed to toggle this.

[image]